# AppleScript: How to make a "type class" with four zero-byte values?

Tags: applescript

"Type class" values in AppleScript look like this:

`«class TEXT»`

The receiving app then gets a 32 bit value of type `OSType` (or `ResType`).

I need to set a property to a value that equals zero as the 32 bit value. In other words, I need to define a `«class »` that contains four NUL characters.

The receiving property is declared as follows in the .sdef file:

```
<property name="scrap type" code="Scrp" type="type">
    <cocoa key="scrapType"/>
</property>
```

Is that possible?

Comment: What's the goal of this extraordinary type? At least it's certainly not *human readable*. I doubt that `FourCharCode` and sdef files consider characters < 0x20

Comment: The goal is to pass a value of 0 to a OSType property in my app. Internal logics simply require this, at least for backward compatibility (I'm in a catch-22 where I can't deliver an update of the app to solve this in a better way, yet.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this will work:

```c
use framework "Foundation"

(current application's NSAppleEventDescriptor's ¬
    descriptorWithTypeCode:0) as anything
    --> «class »
```

**EDIT:** 2019-04-28

As noted in the comments, the `anything` (or `any`) class in AppleScript, which *can* be used to coerce cocoa values to their AppleScript equivalents, is not the ideal means of doing this.  Instead, adding cocoa objects to an `NSArray` and then coercing this to a `list` will coerce all values in the array to their AppleScript types.  So:

```c
item 1 of ((current application's NSArray's ¬
    arrayWithObject:(current application's ¬
        NSAppleEventDescriptor's ¬
        descriptorWithTypeCode:0)) as list)
```

Comment: Doesn't work here. SD shows it as a `<NSAppleEventDescriptor '>` (value: `«class ocid» id «data optr0000000080B0020080600000»`), not as «class ....». But you do? Strange.

Comment: Oh, I need to use it outside of "tell app ...". Then it works. Perfect!

Comment: A slightly safer solution is, according to Shane Stanley (https://forum.latenightsw.com/t/how-to-make-a-type-class-of-value-zero-four-bytes-of-0/1917/4?u=tempelmann), is: `item 1 of ((current application's NSArray's arrayWithObject:(current application's NSAppleEventDescriptor's descriptorWithTypeCode:0)) as list)`

Comment: Oh, of course, I should’ve thought of that. `anything` isn’t ideal to use.  I’ll add an edit to the answer to include that recommendation by Shane, for future users to benefit.

Comment: Actually, one could even coerce the value immediately to `type class` instead: `(current application's NSAppleEventDescriptor's descriptorWithTypeCode:0) as type class`.  I wonder if that's allowable in an "official" sense.